# Producing xml file in SLD to add discrete colors and color legend

Tags: geoserver, sld, xml

I have to produce a xml file, according to Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) (for more informations you can see: http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld). The file is required by GeoServer and it has the purpose to add a color legend.

How would this xml file be written, according to standard SLD ?

Can you indicate me some link with examples?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about "MaxScaleDenominator" and "MinScaleDenominator" [in this page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rules.html#scale-selection), and then define the "size" for each range.

See this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0-.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>layer</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Name>default</Name>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                   <!--Change here the scale of this range -->
                   <MaxScaleDenominator>20000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                   <PointSymbolizer>
                     <Graphic>
                        <ExternalGraphic>
                            <!--put here the image link -->
                            <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"
                                xlink:href="/path/to/image.png" />
                            <Format>image/png</Format>
                        </ExternalGraphic>
                       <!--Define here the size of this range -->
                       <Size>10</Size>
                     </Graphic>
                   </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                   <!--Change here the scale of this range -->
                   <MinScaleDenominator>20000</MinScaleDenominator>
                   <PointSymbolizer>
                     <Graphic>
                        <ExternalGraphic>
                            <!--put here the image link -->
                            <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"
                                xlink:href="/path/to/image.png" />
                            <Format>image/png</Format>
                        </ExternalGraphic>
                       <!--Define here the size of this range -->
                       <Size>4</Size>
                     </Graphic>
                   </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the **values** of the pixels then you need a RasterSymbolizer and a ColorRamp - see the [SLD Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/rasters.html) for examples. For a "rainbow" type image look at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/rasters.html#many-color-gradient